# How to use Zend_Http to send and receive files

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-http-client

My client code is:

```
$Client = new Zend_Http_Client(
        $url,
        array(
          'maxredirects' => 1,
          'timeout'      => 5,
          'useragent'    => 'LMS_LiveAccess'
        )
);
$Client->resetParameters();
$Client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
$Client->setFileUpload('/home/itaymoav/outer.xml','outer.xml');
$Client->request();
```

On my server, when I do `var_dump($_FILES)` I do see the file name and the correct size.

```
outer_xml = Array
(
name = outer.xml
type = text/plain
tmp_name = /home/itaymoav/files/phpecWKHK
error = 0
size = 1752
)
```

But when I go to the temp folder (where the `$_FILES` tells me it saved the file) it is empty.
I both tried the tmp folder and a different folder with chmod 777. nothing.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the uploaded file, you must move them to another location, like this.

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), it says,

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of
>   the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) is an simple example.